# Ошибка TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable при операции с объектом списка

Tags: python

```
for x in range(0, n):
    te = d[x] % 2
```

При смене типа данных на Float выдаёт всё то же. Заранее спасибо за внимание!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

а переменная `d` у вас какого типа?
очень похоже, что `int`, а не `list`

т.е. когда вы пытаетесь обратиться к `int` как к массиву возникает

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

простой пример

```
x = 11
print(x[0] % 3)
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое за помощь!